# Unable to review suggested edit from Moderator Dashboard

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

If there's a suggested edit on a post & if you try to review the suggested edit from the [Moderator Dashboard](/admin/dashboard), then process fails.

The pending edit indicator is shown, but if you click on it, Chrome refreshes the entire page instead of showing the suggested edit, while IE9 just does.. nothing.

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Seems to be fine in Chrome now. Don't have access to IE9